# Summary page for crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report that gathers information for health insurance groups such as members, loss ratios, premiums paid, etc.  The report is grouped such that each health insurance group is displayed on their own page.

I'd like to create a summary page for this report that displays the health insurance groups all in one column with certain pieces of information from the main report in their own separate columns.

I'm inexperienced with crystal reports and I can't seem to find a way to easily accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: create a sub report and place it in report footer

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but ran into a new snag.  Some of the items I'd like to place in the summary are shared variables from other subreports.  When I attempt to drop them into the summary report they take the value from the last group on the main report.

Comment: Create different shared variables if each group and use those in final sub report

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  If I have over 100 groups do I need to create a variable for each group?

Comment: If you are pulling 100 different values then  you need 100 shared variables, else you need only one